# Creating a snapshot for a proxmox VM is not possible either in the GUI or CLI

Tags: virtual-machine, snapshot, proxmox

I'm trying to make a snapshot of one of my VMs via the GUI but the button to creat the snapshot is greyed out, so I wanted to try and do it using the CLI so I could see any helpful output and I got this:

```
 pct snapshot 106 "testing"
Configuration file 'nodes/pve01/lxc/106.conf' does not exist
```

the list of my VMS:

```
qm list
 VMID NAME                 STATUS     MEM(MB)    BOOTDISK(GB) PID            
 106 TestingServer        running    1024              32.00 23131
```

I'm not sure what's this about so I was trying to see if somebody here could please give me a hand, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue on some of the volumes I've attached. So basically, there's a very specific requirement for the storage type you need to have in order to make a snapshot of VM. The list below has the requirements and you can find more information here https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Storage#_storage_types

[image: Storage type requirements]

Hope this helps.

> You can check the storage type by going to  **Datacenter** > **Storage**

Once storage is created you cannot change the type of that storage.

Answer (score 0):

The command 'pct snapshot' is a command to snapshot a container (not a QEMU VM). The error is indicating that it can't find a container (LXC) with VM ID 106:

```
Configuration file 'nodes/pve01/lxc/106.conf' does not exist
```

The LXC in the path here indicates that it is looking for an LXC container. Your command 'qm list' lists QEMU VMs (not containers). So you are using the wrong command.

You need 'qm snapshot' instead of 'pct snapshot'.